# How to access soy file from ftl file

Tags: templates, freemarker, jive

I want to access one of the element in soy file by its id from ftl file.
I tried <#include "path to soy file.soy"/> but did not work.

What is the syntax to include/import soy file in ftl file?

Comment: there is no error but the element in soy file is not getting accessed in ftl

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen. With `#include`, FreeMarker just inserts the content of soy file into the output of the template as is. So if you are running the soy in the browser, it should work or not regardless of FreeMarker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I try with #include, the entire soy file code comes shows on browser when I run the application.

Comment: Just to be sure it's clear, there's no connection between Soy and FreeMarker. I guess you are supposed to pass the Soy content to a JavaScript function or something. Figure that out first; how would you do it without FreeMarker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

<@soy.render template="" data= />

https://community.jivesoftware.com/docs/DOC-42113#jive_content_id_Rendering_a_Soy_Template_from_within_a_Freemarker_Template